# How to get current hour and keep track

Tags: javascript

I am quit new to Javascript and currently working on a map (Raphael) where I am placing a line-graph above wich shows live traffic per hour. I am checking every minute what the current hour is via;

```
setInterval(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var hour = d.getHours();
}, 60000);
```

But it looks like the current hour is only set after the 60 seconds.
I want to get the current hour right away and also check for it every minute.

Hope I made myself clear and this question will help others too..

Comment: No, the current hour is available immediately whenever you ask for it. Your timer function successfully fetches the time and the hour, but it doesn't do anything with it. In other words, your function will have absolutely no effect on its surroundings.

Comment: You can just make a function out of it and run it right away and then trigger the set interval. Set interval runs first after the timeout you set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A interval doesn't run when made, you can create a function or re-write what's inside the interval

function:

```
var hour;

function getHour() {
    var d = new Date();
    hour = d.getHours();
}

setInterval(getHour, 60000);
getHour();
```

or re-write:

```
var hour;

setInterval(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    hour = d.getHours();
}, 60000);

var d = new Date();
hour = d.getHours();
```

Comment: The second code-block worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function getHour() {
  var d = new Date();
  var hour = d.getHours();
}

getHour();
setInterval(getHour, 60000);
```

Comment: Some additional explanation would probably help.

Comment: well i thought it was self explanatory

Comment: To me, it certainly is, but the OP indicated that he is very new to JavaScript. So I'd say adding a sentence or two can't hurt.

Comment: new to javascript doesn't mean new to algorithms :) anyway I saw that many people posted answers similar to mine so I didn't bother..

Comment: Indeed, as I am new to Javascript all the answers looked the same at first, but with a small description it would be easier to understand the difference between each answer. (I know it is also good to analyse them each from a learning perspective) When there is a small explanation it is easier to get the idea behind every answer..

Answer (score 0):

Just before add this :

```
var d = new Date();
var hour = d.getHours();

setInterval(function(){
    d = new Date();
    hour = d.getHours();
}, 60000);
```

You have to check the hour one time manually before the timer ;)